# Got an error while installing turtle library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

The error given below:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\soura\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\soura\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fovg_cud\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\soura\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fovg_cud\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr
(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --eg
g-base 'C:\Users\soura\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fovg_cud\turtle\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\soura\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fovg_cud\turtle\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\soura\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fovg_cud\turtle\setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The error message is really hard to read. Please use code tags to format the message.

Comment: Your error says "Check the logs for full command output".  Find where your log file is and open it to discover a more substantive error.

Comment: The `except` error looks like you are using a python2 program with python 3

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a syntactic error next to an `except` in your code.

According to the error, you need to change line 1 to:

```py
except ValueError:
    #your code here
```

Hope this helps!!